# Simple method for viewing DataTables (jQuery) in a Python app?

Tags: jquery, python, r, datatable, datatables

I love the cleanliness and simplicity of [DataTables](http://datatables.net/), a jQuery plugin.

For R, the RStudio folks have put together a simple package ([DT](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/)) that enables you to create a "hello world" DataTable [in two lines](http://www.r-bloggers.com/dt-an-r-interface-to-the-datatables-library/):

```
library(DT)
DT::datatable(iris)
```

Are there any simple integrations of DataTables for Python, which wouldn't require setting up HTML templates etc as well?

Or, since I really just love DataTables for the ability to quickly filter by columns like below, are there other packages I should use instead?

[image: datatables]

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Bumping this question, also interested

Comment: Sadly I never found a good solution! And I don't use `r` these days...